# How to extract and parse out string fields in string text files

Tags: python

I am trying to parse out a couple of numbers and names from lines of string text example below.
The file is similar to the format below.

```
1. 00054 **/ 063076600 NAME** Days Off: 21 Cr:021:00 
2. CAPS ALLL +++ VSVS
3. more lines of text
4. 00054 / 063076600 NAME Days Off: 21 Cr:074:30 
5. CAPS ALLL +++ VSVS
6. more lines of text....
```

I need to parse out  the number(063076600) and name(NAME) that follow the '/'.
The lines that contain these fields always contain the “/” before it. Also the NAME is in all Caps.
I tried using str.isupper() for the name field but a lot of the text I do not need is in all caps like line 2 so this won't work.

Is there some way I can specify how to get the 2 items after the “/” and add them to a list?

```
fname =raw_input('Enter the filename:')
listOfnames = []
try:
   fhand = open(fname)
except:
   print 'File cannot be opened',fname
   exit()
count = 0
with open(fname) as f:
   for line in f:
       # break line to words
       for word in line.strip().split():
           if word.startswith('/'):
            #get the number after "/" and append
            #get the NAME and append
               count = count + 1
               listOfnames.append(word)
               try:
                   print "number is", number
                   print "name is" , name
               except:
                   print "not available"
print listOfnames
print 'count is',count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def handle_input(fhand):
    listofnames = []
    count = 0
    try:
        with open(fhand,'r') as data:
            for i in data:
                if '/' in i:
                    number, name =  filter (lambda x: x,i.split('/')[1].split(' '))[:2]
                    count += 1
                    listofnames.append([name,number])
        if listofnames: print 'count:{}\nnames:\n{}'.format(count,''.join( map(lambda x: "\t{}: {}\n".format(x[0],x[1]),listofnames)))
    except Exception:
        print 'not available'

handle_input('test.txt')
```

result:

```
count:2
names:
    NAME: 063076600
    NAME: 063076600
```

Comment: mitghi, Thank you very much for helping me with a problem I have been struggling with